# Botón ejecuta varias veces una función

Tags: javascript, java, html, sql, jsp

Tengo una tabla en la cual genero las filas dinamicamente y dentro de las mismas hay un botón generado por `jsp`:

Este es el codigo `JSP` para generar las filas:

```
<%
Producto prod=new Producto();            
if(catSeleccionada==null){
LinkedList<EntProducto> lista = prod.ListarProducto("","","");
    for (int i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
    {
    out.println("<tr >");
    out.println("<td>" +lista.get(i).getProdCod()+"</td>");
    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">" +lista.get(i).getProdNom()+"</td>");
    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">" +lista.get(i).getProdIva()+"</td>");
    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">CARGAR IMAGEN</td>");
    out.println("<td >" +"<button class=\"btn btn-primary\" 
    id='"+"btnAct"+i+"' onclick='"+                                
    "prodModi()'"+" value='"+lista.get(i).getProdCod()+
                            "' data-toggle=\"modal\" data-
    target=\"#modalAct\" >"+"Actualizar"+"</button>");
    out.println("</tr>");
                }
}
```

la función en `javascript` es la siguiente:

```
    function prodModi(){
    //var valorId;
    $("button").click(function(){
        var valorId=($(this).attr("id"));
        document.getElementById("inputCodigo").value=document.getElementById(valorId).value;
        $.ajax({
            url:'SrvBuscaProducto',
            data:{codigoProducto:document.getElementById('inputCodigo').value},
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var objeto=eval(data);
                document.getElementById('inputNombre').value=objeto[0].prodNom;
                var categoriaConsultada=objeto[0].prodNomCategoria;
                alert(categoriaConsultada);
                var comboCategoria=document.getElementById('PROD_COD_CAT_BUSCA');
                var cantidadComboCat=comboCategoria.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < cantidadComboCat; i++) {
                    if (comboCategoria[i].value===categoriaConsultada) {
                        comboCategoria[i].selected=true;
                    }
                }
                var ivaConsultado=objeto[0].prodIva;
                if (ivaConsultado==="S") {
                    document.getElementById('opciones_1').checked=true;
                    document.getElementById('ivaGrabado').value="S";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('opciones_2').checked=true;
                    document.getElementById('ivaGrabado').value="N";
                }

                },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('error'+textStatus);
                }
        });
    });
    //alert(document.getElementById(valorId).value);        
    }
```

Al presionar el botón la primera vez ejecuta el código sin embargo cuando presiono nuevamente se ejecuta dos veces y si sigo presionando el botón de la tabla se ejecuta n veces es como si se fueran acumulando y repitiéndose la función, que esta mal

Comment: Estás repitiendo código al hacer $('button').click(), eso ya lo haces con la función onclick

Comment: Si ya lo revise pero si quito esa parte deja de funcionar el botón,  supongo que es porque obtengo el id del botón por medio de this

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que al hacer click, vas al método `prodModi()`, en el cuál estás agregando un evento. Si haces otro click, se agregará nuevamente un evento al mismo botón. Intenta dejando sólo el contenido de `$("button").click(function(){ .... })` en el método `prodModi()`
.

Comment: Si ya lo revise pero si quito esa parte deja de funcionar el botón, supongo que es porque obtengo el id del botón por medio de this

Comment: acabo de cambiar la linea que estaba demás y le puse como parámetro una variable y lo solucione gracias por la observación

Answer (score 1):

yo tenia el mismo problema, tenia el metodo `$("button").click...` dentro de un metodo que mandaba a llamar cada que hacia una busqueda por lo que cada vez le agreagaba el evento al boton era como si le hubiera echo 'n' clics.

En mi caso lo que tuve que hacer fue sacar el evento del metodo de busqueda y con eso que solucionado.

Primero estaba asi:

```
function getDataTable{
...
..
$('button').click(function....
}
```

Para solucionarlo lo deje asi:

```
function getDataTable{...
..
}

$('button').click(function...
```